# Apache Storm: IllegalArgumentException: field supervisor.scheduler.meta must be a 'java.util.Map'

Tags: java, apache-storm, bigdata

I am new to apache storm , currenly trying **Pluggable Scheduler**, to schedule the task assignment: which task should run on which supervisor.

I tried setting the "supervisor.scheduler.meta" value in the storm.yaml file in the supervisor node as shown below and when i tried to run the supervisor i end up with the illegal argument exception.I am using apache storm 0.10.0. Could you please guide me in solving this issue. Please find the configuration files and error logs below

```
storm.yaml
-----------
supervisor.scheduler.meta: "special-supervisor"  


error-log
----
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field supervisor.scheduler.meta 'special-supervisor' must be a 'java.util.Map'
    at backtype.storm.config$fn$reify__880.validateField(config.clj:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
    at backtype.storm.config$validate_configs_with_schemas.invoke(config.clj:118)
    at backtype.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:123)
    at backtype.storm.command.config_value$_main.invoke(config_value.clj:22)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
```

Comment: supervisor.scheduler.meta expects a java Map instance - basically a key value pair. you might want to represent "special-supervisor" or the expected value in a format that represents java Map in yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map entries need to have key and a value. For example:

```
supervisor.scheduler.meta:
  name: "special-supervisor"
```

where "name" is the key and "special-supervisor" is the value.